# Two people with golden medals

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

A duet between two people.

> **(A)** The largest of boards, yet my length is real small.
>   **(B)** A well-known professor, a rock without roll.
>   **(A)** A black body's spectre by my law is bound.
>   **(B)** My famed equation with E is profound.
>   **(both)** QM's foundations by us were laid out.
>   **(both)** Our golden medals deserved were, no doubt.

Who are we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They Are:

> Max Planck & Albert Einstein

Explanation:

> Planck's solution to black body radiation and Einstein's equation E=MC^2 laid the foundation of quantum mechanics, they both won nobel prize (golden medal)

Comment: Well, that didn't take long :D Nice work!

Comment: being a physics nerd paid off here i guess.

Comment: It would be good to explain each clue separately, there are lots of nice wordplay and interesting physics going on in there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add something to the other hints

The largest of boards

> it's a plank, which is a word play on Planck

my length is real small

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length

A well-known professor, a rock without roll.

> Einstein literally translates to "a rock"

A black body's spectre by my law is bound.

> Planck famously was the first to correctly describe black body radiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

My famed equation with E is profound.

> almost everybody has heard of E=mc^2

QM's foundations by us were laid out.
Our golden medals deserved were, no doubt.

> both Einstein and Planck pioneered in Quantum Mechanics and won a nobel prize for discovering energy quantization and describing the photo electric effect

Comment: This is correct. Also largest = max :)

Comment: Oh, nice, I didn't catch that.